# Linear Algebra: how to extrapolate vector from endpoint?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am in uni and was given this problem:

> $T:\mathbb{R}->\mathbb{R}^4$ sends $3$ to $(2,5,1,6)$. Where does it send $7$?

I don't understand how a solution is possible. I assume I must extrapolate a vector from  $(3)$ to $(2, 5, 1, 6)$, but surely there are many ways to do it and many such vectors?

Comment: Are you sure it's not $T: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^4$?  After all, $3\not\in \Bbb R^4$...

Comment: @DavidWheeler Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, $7 \in \mathbb{R}$.

However, if your function is $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^4}$, then by the rule that $T(cx)=cT(x)$, $7$ is sent to the vector $\left(\frac{14}{3},\frac{35}{3},\frac{7}{3},14\right)$, which is $\frac{7}{3}T(3)$